# Count max number of consecutive digit in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Example: `'1234567'` String has : 7 consecutive digits and these are `1234567`
Example : `'123456'` String has : 6 consecutive digits and these are `123456`

I need both the

1. count
2. the digits sequence as output also

Please help, regex or custom function

I had used inefficient brute force approach:

```
var m10 = /^\d{10}$/.exec(str);
var m9 = /^\d{9}$/.exec(str);
var m8 = /^\d{8}$/.exec(str);
```

Using this I need to have m1,m2 to m10 and then use if else to check if the string has 1 or 10 consecutive digits and then output it

Time is important here so trying to find optimize way of doing this.

Comment: First help us to help you, include what you have tried so far. If trying things isn't for you, consider hiring a developer who can

Comment: I had used inefficient brute force approach: var m10 = /^\d{10}$/.exec(str);
 var m9 = /^\d{9}$/.exec(str);
 var m8 = /^\d{8}$/.exec(str); 
using this i need to have m1,m2 to m10 and then use if else to check if string has 1 or 10 consecutive digits and then output it

Comment: please edit the question with what you have tried. Is the regex a requisite here (like wanting to learn them)? because it seems to me a loop would be more appropriate here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the matches using `match` and regex `\d+`

```
var matches = "1234567String".match(/\d+/g);
```

Now get the max value using `reduce`

```
if( matches )
{
    var maxLengthStr = matches.reduce( ( a, c ) => ( c.length > a.length ? c : a ) , "" );
}
```

You can get the length of string as

```
var fnGetMax = str => {
  var matches = "1234567String".match(/\d+/g);
  var maxLengthStr = matches ? matches.reduce( ( a, c ) => (c.length > a.length ? c : a ) , "" ) : "";
  return { value : maxLengthStr , length : maxLengthStr.length }; //return the expression
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var fnGetMax = str => {
  var matches = "1234567String".match(/\d+/g);
  var maxLengthStr = matches ? matches.reduce((a, c) => (c.length > a.length ? c : a), "") : "";
  return {
    value: maxLengthStr, length: maxLengthStr.length
  }; //return the expression
}

console.log( fnGetMax( "34234ksdf34234ssdcs432sadfe34343" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

if performance is what you are looking for, i think you really should consider using a loop, see this example:

**NOTE**: in case of two substring with identical lengths, with this method the first one will be returned (for the last one, use `if(s.length >= saved.length)`). If no substring is found, empty string is currently returned.

```js
var result;

 var fnGetMax = str => {
  var matches = str.match(/\d+/g);
  var maxLengthStr = matches ? matches.reduce((a, c) => (c.length > a.length ? c : a), "") : "";
  return {
  value: maxLengthStr, length: maxLengthStr.length
  }; //return the expression
 }
 
 var s = performance.now();
 console.log( result = fnGetMax( "34234ksdf34234ssdcs432sadfe34343" ) );
 var e = performance.now();
 console.log('time: ', e - s);
 document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = 'REDUCE - string: ' + result.value + ' / length: ' + result.length + ' / timing: ' + (e - s);
 
 var fnGetMax2 = str => {
  var saved = '', s = '', i, l = str.length;
  for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
   if('0123456789'.indexOf(str[i]) !== -1){
    s += str[i];
    if(s.length > saved.length){
     saved = s;
    }
   }else{
    s = '';
   }
  }
  return {
   value: saved, length: saved.length
  }
 }
 
 var s = performance.now();
 console.log( result = fnGetMax2( "34234ksdf34234ssdcs432sadfe34343" ) );
 var e = performance.now();
 console.log('time: ', e - s);
 document.getElementById('result2').innerHTML = 'LOOP - string: ' + result.value + ' / length: ' + result.length + ' / timing: ' + (e - s);
```

```html
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```